# How to map case class as postgresql column in Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, mapper

I have a following data structure:

```
final case class Log(
  id: UUID,
  event: String,
  metadata: Option[List[Metadata]]
)

final case class Metadata(key: String, value: String)
```

for event logs with some optional metadata.
I m trying to persist them in postgresql (v42.2.5) table using Slick (v3.3.3) and Slick-pg (v0.17.3):

```
class LogTable(tag: Tag)
    extends BaseTable[Log](tag, "event") {

  def id: Rep[EventId]                      = column[EventId]("id")
  def event: Rep[String]                    = column[String]("event")
  def metadata: Rep[Option[List[Metadata]]] = column[Option[List[Metadata]]]("metadata")

  override def * =
    (id, event, eventType, metadata) <>
      ((Log.apply _).tupled, Log.unapply _)
}
```

However I get following compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[Option[List[log.domain.Metadata]]]
```

I tried writing custom column mapper:

```
  implicit val metadataColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Metadata, String](
    {
      meta => write(meta) // return string
    }, {
      meta_string => read(meta_string) // return Metadata
    }
  )
```

However this implicit is not considered needed and results in the same error.

How to map `Option[List[Metadata]` correctly?

Comment: Is `EventId` equal to `UUID`?

Comment: Yes, it is a tagged type, no problem here

Comment: (id, event, eventType, metadata)  - eventType- ?
in your case class we can see id, event. metadata

Comment: @syforce Were you able to figure out the mapping? I have a similar use case.

Comment: @eshaingle unfortunaltelly I don't recall my solution from then, so I can't confirm it is doable with above setup.

My intuitnion for now would be to persist metadata as json string and leave parsing out of Slick scope